# Como puedo exportar/importar const app = express() a otro fichero js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy tratando de separar responsabilidades, diviendo en diferentes archios y modulos las diferentes acciones que realizare en mi aplicacion del lado del servidor.

Me te topado con un problema, el cual no puedo entender. Trato de exportar desde el fichero el cual inicia el servidor, la variable `app`, en la cual almaceno `express` de la siguiente manera:

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({api: "Woks Fine"});
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("App Start in Port", app.get('port'));
});

export default app;
```

#### apiGoogleMaps.js

```
import app from '../server.js';

export function respuestaMensaje(apiUrl, app) {
    console.log(apiUrl);
    app.post(apiUrl, (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
}
```

#### adress.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import request from 'superagent';
import { respuestaMensaje } from '../../../src/handlers/apiGoogleMap.js';


class AddressInput extends Component{

    constructor(){    
        super();
        this.state = {
            address: "",
            api:"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",
            direccion: "",
            latitud: "",
            longitud:""
        };
    } 

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

                <form>                
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.updateAdress.bind(this)}/>
                    <button onClick={this.getAddressGeo.bind(this)}>Consultar</button> 
                </form>

                <ul>
                    <li><label>Direccion:</label>{this.state.direccion}</li>
                    <li><label>Latitud:{this.state.latitud}</label></li>
                    <li><label>Longitud:{this.state.longitud}</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        )
    }

    updateAdress(event){
        this.setState({
            address: event.target.value
        });
    }

    getAddressGeo(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        const apiUrl = this.state.api + this.state.address;
        respuestaMensaje(apiUrl);

    } 
}

export default AddressInput;
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "reactnodescaffold",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js",
    "build:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js\" \"webpack --config webpack.config.js\""
  },
  "author": "PterPmntaM",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.38",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "superagent": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

#### Estructura del proyecto

[image: estructura]

Los errores son muchos, pero se que tiene que ver con la importación de la variable.

[Errores que aparecen en consola](https://pastebin.com/t0AJVkLu) cuando intento compilar la web app.

Comment: estás seguro de que estás usando Babel?

Comment: pues claro, si quieres pego aqui el `packge.json`, es mas deja lo pego

Comment: No te preocupes, era solo para asegurarme. Aveces son los pequeños detalles.

Comment: @DiesanRomero ya puse todo el codigo que se supone que debe funcionar, podrias echarle un ojo

Answer (score 0):

veo algún error de syntaxis que podría ser la razón, para exportar un custom module la syntaxis correcta es esta según documentación oficial:

```
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
 return "HELLO";
};
```

Y para requerir un módulo yo lo utilizo con:

```
var modulo = require('pathArchive');
```

Es posible de todas maneras que tengas otros errores, en fin te dejo ese ejemplo.

Link de documentación: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module

Saludos

**** EDIT ****

```js
//ARCHIVO APP.JS (principal)
//en este inicias express y configuras los set por ejemplo app.set(...)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Aquí haces el llamado a tu custom module de rutas por ejemplo.
var router = require('../module-router.js');


app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  
   router.routeo(req, res);
  
});

app.listen(3000);
// -- FIN ARCHIVO PRINCIPAL



//ARCHIVO module-router.js
var routeo = function(req, res){

   switch(req.url){
   case '/home':
      //aqui lo que quieras que haga al llegar a /home
   break;
   case '/contact':
      //aqui lo que quieras que haga al llegar a /contact
   break;
   default:
      //aqui entrará todo lo que no cumpla con los cases ejemplo un 404
   
   }
  
}

//con module.exports es un objeto al que le dirás qué dunciones quieres que sean exportadas
module.exports = {

  routeo

}
// -- FIN ARCHIVO module-router.js
```

Por lo tanto de esta manera lo que estarás haciendo es dejando todo el ruteo de tu app en un archivo siendo más fácil de entender el sistema, lo mismo haces para cada componente.

Espero se pueda entender, recuerda que es un simple ejemplo.

Saludos

Comment: Disculpa, y si es la variable app y no un modulo como tal?

Comment: Recuerda que app "const app = express();" también contiene express, por lo que también deberías incluirlo en el mismo archivo, no obstante te recomiendo re formules la estructura que vas a utilizar, en general express y app y sus sets, quedan en el achivo principal de tu aplicación y los modulos los cargas en ese archivo o de hecho te creas sub archivos para que quede más limpio.

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo, si no es mucha molestia

Comment: Te dejé editada la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Gracias, lo probare el sábado le paso algo al r de mi casa, y como es festivo toca esperar hasta el fin de semana.

Comment: Excelente, recuerda porfavor, si te sirve lo explicado dar la respuesta como Resuelta.

Comment: Hola, disculpa, hice algo parecido, [codigo probado de esta forma](https://pastebin.com/MMqNUw7y), y me sigue saliendo `post is undefined`

Comment: Según la consola ese post undefined sobre qué archivo te lo muestra? necesitaría un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Puedes ir al chat, el problema no era cosa de Node o express, si no de webpack

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75332/discussion-between-jonathan-schell-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).

Comment: Estoy ya en el chat amigo